# Why keyof operator retreives non enumerable inherited? properties from object literal type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typeerror, javascript-objects

Please, consider this TypeScript code:

```
'use strict';

type Value = 1 | 2 ;
type Owner = 'ownerA' | 'ownerB';
type ItemType = 'itemTypeA' | 'itemTypeB';
type Item = {
  type: ItemType;
  owner: Owner;
  value: Value;
};

type AnotherType = {
  [k in keyof Item]: null | {
    [m in keyof Item[k]]: number;
  };
};

const v: AnotherType = {
  type: { itemTypeA: 0, itemTypeB: 1,},
  owner: { ownerA: 0, ownerB: 1,},
  value: null,
};

console.log(v);
```

The `tsc` throws an error in this case:

> error TS2322: Type '{ itemTypeA: number; itemTypeB: number; }' is not
> assignable to type '{ [x: number]: number; toString: number; charAt:
> number; charCodeAt: number; concat: number; indexOf: number;
> lastIndexOf: number; localeCompare: …

Apparently the `[m in keyof Item[k]]: number;` iteration for some reason includes the non-enumerable, even non-present properties (not sure if an object type can inherit from Object.prototype's type) like: charCodeAt, charAt etc.

Up to my knowledge this contradicts [the documentation on the 'keyof' type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator), which is described as:

> The keyof operator takes an object type and produces a string or
> numeric literal union of its keys. The following type P is the same
> type as type P = "x" | "y": `type Point = { x: number; y: number };  type P = keyof Point;`

i.e. there are no 'charAt' et al. values in the produced union, only 'x' and 'y'.

**May be it has something to do with the `in` operator**, but again, in JS it traverses only thru enumerable properties of an object (not sure if that's true in TypeScript when it's used as a type operator).

Could someone please explain, what's happening here?

Comment: `Item[K]` is the type you want to iterate over, not `keyof Item[K]` (which is saying "keys of some strings", like `toUpperCase`, etc).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5kZMW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: indeed, sorry for a silly question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your type to something like

```
type AnotherType = {
    [K in keyof Item]: null | {
        [M in Item[K]]: number; // <-- no keyof
    };
};
```

where you don't use [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) inside the nested [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

The problem with `M in keyof Item[K]` is that `Item[K]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the `Item` interface, and thus one of `ItemType`, `Owner`, or `Value`, which are already the [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of key-like [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) you want.  And since `Item[K]` is already keylike, writing `keyof Item[K]` is evaluating keys-of-keys.  Presumably you don't care about the keys of strings like `"ownerA"` (e.g., `"toUpperCase"`, `"length"`, etc) or the keys of numbers like `1` (e.g., `"toFixed"`). Instead you should just iterate over `Item[K]` directly. After all, we want `{[M in Owner]: number}`, nut `{[M in keyof Owner]: number}`.

After we make that change, `AnotherType` is equivalent to

```
type AnotherType = {
    type: {
        itemTypeA: number;
        itemTypeB: number;
    } | null;
    owner: {
        ownerA: number;
        ownerB: number;
    } | null;
    value: {
        1: number;
        2: number;
    } | null;
}
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQIxQD5QEwDcAUKJFAPIDuAdhAE5ToDkA9jfQIJM5Svt0AhJsVLQAksAgBbACrg0vAJaTZ8rjybLpcyEJHyoE6YygBvIlEtRRALkMqdEYlahtadO1XfOrAN0QodvDITkQAvsQkBhzULMAAFvSOJuYuANoA0lCK1FAA1hAgLABm9tIAunbUSAgIPKkuVmkAstm5RlKZ5ZVQ1VIARvQ+lhHhxAD0AFTW0bEJSQboDZa2ZhaNllqqkBxVSAND6xtbjgJ7B3TDUGE81bVXbvR2y42PdLu9+4OXR6-8Z58Llcbrg7ggrv4Qs9fi4MOdvlcXHh4YcXCDPvdwlBJuMiEQAMYsagAZ2AUF8dhicUSdGSS1+q1M2QcajsAAYADTM7TyAEYLlhDm-N7PVz8D6csXuPkCoUuSGBDEIIWjAlE4ksBAQAB0CBYAHMABS+ACUBCAA)